# Uncaught ReferenceError: cbfunc is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i currently having

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: cbfunc is not defined"

problem in my development

```
.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, httpGetData) {

console.log($stateParams.catID);

$scope.items = [];

httpGetData.getTerkini().success(function(response){
$scope.items = response.rss.channel.item;

});
```

});

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('httpGetData', function($http){

     var dataItems = {};

     dataItems.getTerkini = function(){
         return $http({

             method: 'JSONP',
             url:'http://json2jsonp.com/?callback=cbfunc&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffullcontentrss.com%2Ffeed.php%3Furl%3Dwww.bharian.com.my%252Fterkini.xml%26key%3D2%26hash%3D3b961c45997507e9d86fae68fa34a216ee866830%26max%3D10%26links%3Dpreserve%26exc%3D%26format%3Djson'

         });         
     }
    return dataItems;

});
```

can some one help me? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer is just change the URL to standard JSONP format which the callback must be in callback=JSON_CALLBACK.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not returning a promise in your factory. Change to:

```
     return $http({

         method: 'JSONP',
         url:'http://json2jsonp.com/?callback=cbfunc&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffullcontentrss.com%2Ffeed.php%3Furl%3Dwww.bharian.com.my%252Fterkini.xml%26key%3D2%26hash%3D3b961c45997507e9d86fae68fa34a216ee866830%26max%3D10%26links%3Dpreserve%26exc%3D%26format%3Djson'

     }).then(function(response) { //promise here
           return response;
     })
```

Secondly, in your api, you are declaring a handler 'cbfunc' for the api response, so you would need to define it in your controller:

```
function cbfunc(response) {
    console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: Hi, it keep say that my callback "cbfunc" is not defined

Comment: I think you will have to define a function 'cbfunc' to handle the response.

Comment: i have try your method, but the result also same, having error on call back not defined

Answer (score -1):

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('httpGetData', function($http){

 var dataItems = {};

 dataItems.getTerkini = function(){
     return $http({

         .....

     });         
 }
return dataItems;
```

Now look at your code. Your dataItems is an object. so in order to access or call getTerkini function you need to write

**httpGetData.dataItems.getTerkini()**

But rather than doing this, what you can do is,

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('httpGetData', function($http){
return {
 var dataItems = {};  // I don't understand the purpose of having dataItmes. basically what you can do is, you can use it within factory. but if you want to return it than your way would be cool.
 getTerkini = function(){
     return $http({
        ..... //function is going to return promise which can be caught at controller.
     });         
 }
});
```

so, you can call it like,

**httpGetData.getTerkini()**